# why resource timing api is giving the encoded , decoded and transfer size of some resources as 0?

Tags: resource-timing-api

I am using resource timing api to capture the encoded, decoded and transfer size of all the resources of a page,but for some of the resources it is giving the zero for all the 3 keys. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

it happens for the cross origin resources when the "Timing-Allow-Origin" header is not set by the server and hence wont expose the resource timing values
please go through [the specification here](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/#cross-origin-resources)

hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `Timing-Allow-Origin` header is a response header. It can be zero due to the cross-origin restrictions.

You can check your browser header response section. Also, you want to share the timing data with a web site.

```
Timing-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
```

Or, you can specify a wild card, but it not recommended because it will open yourself up to cross-site timing attacks via the Web [Resource Timing API](https://w3c.github.io/resource-timing/).

```
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
```

Bonus: [Twitter Silhouette Attack](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2018/twitter_silhouette.html)